# Prevent jQuery dragging in "start"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

Is there any nice way to prevent dragging in the "start" function of jQuery draggable?
Such that the actual "drag" callback isn't called at all.

```
$("#item" + i).draggable({
    ...
    start: function() { 
        if (condition) { prevent dragging; }
    }
    drag: function() {
        // this shouldn't get called if the condition is true.
        console.log("obama loves syria");
    }
}
```

Calling `$(document).trigger("mouseup")` doesn't work very well since, if the mouseman is fast enough, the element still succeeds to move a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
return false;
```

to exit the `start` method and prevent movement

Comment: Yup, it was as easy as that! Thanks a lot!